# Automatic scrolling to keep child element in the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a parent div called `lyricpadding`, and inside I have a lot of `<h4>`'s with a unique ID. Anyways, what I need to do us, by using preferably Jquery or Javascript or CSS, is to keep the `<h4>` marked with the class of `highlighted` in the middle of the parent container, but I don't want it to stretch over the whole thing, I just want the text to be centered by an automatic scroll until it gets to the bottom. So the div with the class `highlighted` will always be visible, preferably in the center.

Comment: If you could put your current markup and css in a fiddle it would be easier to visualise. My gut feeling is you're going to have to position it absolutely and update its location relative to scrollX and scrollY with jQuery events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jQuery example. It uses position absolute and then adjusts according to the scroll position and window size. See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYNxA/1/)**.

HTML:

```
<div class='lyricpadding'>
    <h4 class='highlighted'>Highlighted</h4>
    <h4>Other</h4>
    <h4>Other</h4>
    <h4>Other</h4>
    <h4>Other</h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lyricpadding
{
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;   
    background-color:lightblue;
}
.highlighted
{    
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function positionMiddle()
{
    var $highlighted = $('.highlighted');    
    $highlighted.css({        
        left: ($(window).width() - $highlighted.outerWidth())/2,
        top: $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() - $highlighted.outerHeight())/2
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(){
   positionMiddle();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){    
   positionMiddle();
});

// To initially run the function:
positionMiddle();
```